# Which server CA to use for device fleet management?

Tags: tls, digital-signature

(I likely didn't use correct keywords, but I was not able to have a complete info about below question).

Working on a IoT device, capable to connect to our own server, using MQTT and HTTPS connections, both utilizing TLS handshake. We want to make sure, that only our devices can connect to our server, the procedure we are thinking:

- Each device will have its own public/private key pair, or better, certificate + associate private key, stored encrypted on the device (or on external EAL5+ certified chip, this is TBC). Certificate is to be signed by the server certificate (Q1) and will contain the device UUID, that will also be stored on the server's database. Client will share certificate with server + response to the challenge, and both will be checked by server if valid. This is how server will authenticate IoT device.
- Each device must have server certificate, this is required for mutual authentication. We also want to authenticate server. Same certificate should also be used to verify new firmware update authenticity (digital signature).

As simple as it gets, we are wondering how to handle certificate updates, if this would ever be needed, due to potential data leak on the server (we are not worried on the client due to EAL5+ certified device).

Should each device store server's ROOTCA and rely that during TLS handshake, server will provide full chain (with ROOTCA as potential exception) of certificates, or do we need to store some intermediate certificates?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: *Client will share certificate with server + response to the challenge, and both will be checked by server if valid.* It's not clear if you're designing your own auth protocol, but you mentioned TLS so why not just use TLS client auth. *Each device must have server certificate, this is required for mutual authentication.* Not really, the IoT devices just need the CA certificate that signed the server certificate. So just the ROOTCA needs to be stored. These are just general thoughts, the details of your scenario might change the analysis.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk yes I fully agree on the which server's certificate we need to store with you. But what if certificate that signed server's certificate isn't the root? Do we need to store the true ROOT up to the chain and will server present all the intermediate in the chain during handshake? Because CA and ROOTCA isn't the same thing in my view.

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk and if I may also ask: For firmware update, we indeed want PKI to verify signature has been signed by our server. For that, do I need server's certificate on my device, or shall we rather use the CA which signed servers certificate, to also sign firmware (using ECDSA in this case)? Main concern is, if server certificate changes, then signing the firmware with new PRIV key will not give positive result on the device checking with old public key. I guess we need a way to update server certificate in the device, for the firmware update purposes.